# opencv - matchTemplate

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am new to opencv.

I have a piece of code that finds a match to my template.

```
 public static void findTemplete(String inFile, String templateFile, String outFile, int match_method) {
    System.out.println("\nRunning Template Matching");

    Mat img = Highgui.imread(inFile);
    Mat templ = Highgui.imread(templateFile);

    int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
    Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
    Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

    MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

    Point matchLoc;
    if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
        matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
    } else {
        matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
    }

    Core.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
            matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));

    System.out.println("Writing "+ outFile);
    Highgui.imwrite(outFile, img);

}
```

My problem is that matchTemplate finds "The best match". So if my templete doesnt exists at all in the picture it finds something anyhow.

So how can i set the "Match strength", so that only strong matches will be found.

Comment: maybe have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762846/matchtemplate-with-opencv-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Normalize after your match Template. This will not allow the minmaxloc to give you proper numbers.

Here is an example:

```c++
  double minVal; double maxVal=0; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
        Point matchLoc;
        matchTemplate ( frame, objectToFind, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED );
        minMaxLoc ( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat ( ) );


        matchLoc = maxLoc;


        if ( maxVal > .995 )
{ 
         //we have a good match so do something 
          }
```

the .995 is what you change to a different number to help remove the bad matches.

Since we arbitrarily set this number, have it output the current value in your console using something like:

```cpp
printf("My current maxVal: %f \n", maxVal);
```

This will help you gauge what you should set your value to.

Hope this helps :)